# Can't get Windows password when trying to connect to AWS Windows Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

When I want to connect to my instance I get this message:
[image]

I waited several minutes but I still get the same message.

System log:
[image]
How can I get the password?

Comment: Is this a newly-launched Amazon EC2 instance from a standard AMI provided in the EC2 management console? If so, either wait or do a Restart on the instance, wait for it to boot, and try again.

Comment: It is launched from a customized AMI..I did wait and restart it but didn't work..

Comment: You can use **Get System Log** and **Get Instance Screenshot** to try and see what's happening.

Comment: I have post the system logs above , can you please have a look? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: It looks like it is booting up, but if things aren't working then try launching another one and see if it is any better. This should not normally be necessary, but it isn't obvious what is going wrong.